# .NET Publish not yielding same results as manual copy

Tags: .net, deployment, publish

I am using Visual Studio 2008 .NET and trying to use the 'Publish' option from the context menu when I right-click on the project file.  Ideally, this would deploy only the files needed to run the project.  I have selected to delete all files before I deploy, include the App_Data folder and only the file needed to run the project.  My project has several .dlls from other projects that are properly referenced.

My issue is the following...if I manually copy the entire project from my local drive to the application server I don't run into any issues, however, if I use the 'Publish' option I can get the application to run on the app server but I eventually run into a Forms Authentication Error.  I have checked the account referenced in the error from the EventViewer and that account is db_owner in the database and has not been locked out.

I am quite perplexed....any ideas?

It appears this only happens when I select the option to include only files needed to run the application.  If I publish ALL files I don't have the error.

Comment: what error you are getting exactly ? Also validate all files if there in bin and main folder after publishing.